# Can a C# Multithreaded Application use separate WorkingDirectories per thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In C# (.NET), can two threads running in the same application have DIFFERENT "WorkingFolders"??

As best I can tell, the answer would be "NO". I think the WORKING DIR is set by the PROCESS in Win32.. Am I wrong here?

According to the following test code, (as well the Win32 `SetCurrentDirectory` API call), this is NOT possible, but has anyone figured out a way to MAKE it possible?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class TestClass {

  public  ManualResetEvent _ThreadDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

  public static void Main() {
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);

    Thread _Thread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Go));
    TestClass test = new TestClass();

    _Thread.Start(test);
    if(test._ThreadDone.WaitOne()) {
      Console.WriteLine("Thread done.  Checking Working Dir...");
      Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    }
  }

  public static void Go(object instance) {
    TestClass m_Test = instance as TestClass;
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    System.IO.Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("L:\\Projects\\");
    Console.WriteLine(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
    m_Test._ThreadDone.Set();
  }
}
```

I know SOMEONE out there has to have ran across this before!

Comment: What is your goal in attempting this?  It's typically better to just design your code to allow you to pass in appropriate folders...

Comment: Possibly by creating a separate app domain per thread. I've added this as a comment as I'm currently unable to show an example.

Comment: @MarcF App Domains won't change the one Environment set per Process (FYI).

Comment: @ErikPhilips - My guess was posted before any other answers. I happily stand corrected.

Comment: It is a global variable that isn't [ThreadStatic].  So of course it is possible.  You don't need threads either, many a program has fallen over from an OpenFileDialog with its RestoreDirectory property set to the default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm going to guess what you're *trying* to do is to make code such as `File.Open("Foo.txt")` behave differently on different threads.  Can you do this?  The short answer is *No* - nor should you be *trying* to do this.  On Windows, the current working directory is set at the process level.  The .NET framework does not violate that rule.

A better approach would be to create an abstraction on top of `Environment.CurrentDirectory` that is thread specific.  Something like:

```
public static class ThreadEnvironment
{
   [ThreadStatic]
   static string _currentDir;

   public static string CurrentDirectory
   {
      get
      {
         if (_currentDir == null) // If Current Directory has not been set on this thread yet, set it to the process default
         {
            _currentDir = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
         }

         return _currentDir;
      }

      set
      {
         if (value == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Cannot set Current Directory to null.");

         _currentDir = value;
      }
   }
}
```

You can then refer to `ThreadEnvironment.CurrentDirectory` to get *that thread's* current directory, which will default to the process directory if it has not been set on that thread.  For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   (new Thread(Thread1)).Start();
   (new Thread(Thread2)).Start();
}

static void Thread1()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Thread1 Working Dir is: {0}", ThreadEnvironment.CurrentDirectory);
   ThreadEnvironment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\";
   Console.WriteLine("Thread1 Working Dir is: {0}", ThreadEnvironment.CurrentDirectory);
}

static void Thread2()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Thread2 Working Dir is: {0}", ThreadEnvironment.CurrentDirectory);
   ThreadEnvironment.CurrentDirectory = @"C:\Windows";
   Console.WriteLine("Thread2 Working Dir is: {0}", ThreadEnvironment.CurrentDirectory);
}
```

You would, of course, then need to qualify that path whenever dealing with file IO, however this is arguably a safer design anyway.

Comment: What about creating different `AppDomain`s and set `AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath` there? That way he can somehow "set" it. Maybe I am mistaken

Comment: I think the goal here was to make `File.Open("Foo.txt")` behave differently on different threads.  And the answer is no, you cannot do that nor should you be trying to do that.

Answer (score 4):

> has anyone figured out a way to MAKE it possible?

It's simply *not possible*.  You can't even have different working directories per App Domain.

The windows rule is: one Environment set per Process. Running in .NET won't change the basic rules.

Instead of that, if you experienced problem in loading assemblies, consider adding the corresponding folder to the PATH environment variable.

Comment: Thanks Erik, this is what I was suspect of, but I think so far, I think Mike Christensen has the best answer... This allows me to hardcode the CurrentDir + Passed Path/File to my IO functions and allow the activity I'm looking for.  But, because of the Win32 documentation, I was afraid this was the case...